# YouTube Video Doesn't Load on Mobile Device (Embedded in a Lightbox)

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I have a **YouTube video** embedded, and it opens inside a Javascript called **VideoBox**. (Sorta like Lightbox)

Everything works fine on my site, but not so much when I try to open it on my iPhone. I suspect it's the way I've embedded it, but I could only find one way that worked with **autoplay enabled** (because I want the video to start when the link is clicked).

**Also**, the Videobox/lightbox works on my phone. It opens up a box with the caption I've included, but the video doesn't load.

This script uses the link only, so I don't have the option of using an iFrame... I don't think.

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/2sAnENc6ObI&autoplay=1" rel="vidbox" 
title="The Rainbox Connection">
<img src="playbtn.png" class="fakeplay" alt="Play Button">
The Rainbow Connection (Video)</a>
```

I don't think the VideoBox is the problem, but just in case... here's the Javascript for that.

**VideoBox:**

```
var Videobox = {

init: function (options) {
    // init default options
    this.options = Object.extend({
        resizeDuration: 400,    // Duration of height and width resizing (ms)
        initialWidth: 250,      // Initial width of the box (px)
        initialHeight: 250,     // Initial height of the box (px)
        defaultWidth: 625,      // Default width of the box (px)
        defaultHeight: 350, // Default height of the box (px)
        animateCaption: true,   // Enable/Disable caption animation
        flvplayer: 'swf/flvplayer.swf'
    }, options || {});

    this.anchors = [];
    $A($$('a')).each(function(el){
        if(el.rel && el.href && el.rel.test('^vidbox', 'i')) {
            el.addEvent('click', function (e) {
      e = new Event(e);
      e.stop();
      this.click(el);
            }.bind(this));
            this.anchors.push(el);
        }
}, this);

    this.overlay = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbOverlay').injectInside(document.body);
    this.center = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbCenter').setStyles({width: this.options.initialWidth+'px', height: this.options.initialHeight+'px', marginLeft: '-'+(this.options.initialWidth/2)+'px', display: 'none'}).injectInside(document.body);

    this.bottomContainer = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbBottomContainer').setStyle('display', 'none').injectInside(document.body);
    this.bottom = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbBottom').injectInside(this.bottomContainer);
    new Element('a').setProperties({id: 'lbCloseLink', href: '#'}).injectInside(this.bottom).onclick = this.overlay.onclick = this.close.bind(this);
    this.caption = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbCaption').injectInside(this.bottom);
    this.number = new Element('div').setProperty('id', 'lbNumber').injectInside(this.bottom);
    new Element('div').setStyle('clear', 'both').injectInside(this.bottom);

    var nextEffect = this.nextEffect.bind(this);
    this.fx = {
        overlay: this.overlay.effect('opacity', {duration: 500}).hide(),
        center: this.center.effects({duration: 500, transition: Fx.Transitions.sineInOut, onComplete: nextEffect}),
        bottom: this.bottom.effect('margin-top', {duration: 400})
    };

},

click: function(link) {

        return this.open (link.href, link.title, link.rel);

},
open: function(sLinkHref, sLinkTitle, sLinkRel) {
    this.href = sLinkHref;
    this.title = sLinkTitle;
    this.rel = sLinkRel;
    this.position();
    this.setup();
    this.video(this.href);
    this.top = Window.getScrollTop() + (Window.getHeight() / 15);
    this.center.setStyles({top: this.top+'px', display: ''});
    this.fx.overlay.start(0.8);
    this.step = 1;
    this.center.setStyle('background','#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat center');
    this.caption.innerHTML = this.title;
    this.fx.center.start({'height': [this.options.contentsHeight]});
},

setup: function(){
    var aDim = this.rel.match(/[0-9]+/g);
    this.options.contentsWidth = (aDim && (aDim[0] > 0)) ? aDim[0] : this.options.defaultWidth;
    this.options.contentsHeight = (aDim && (aDim[1] > 0)) ? aDim[1] : this.options.defaultHeight;

},

position: function(){
this.overlay.setStyles({'top': window.getScrollTop()+'px', 'height': window.getHeight()+'px'});
},

video: function(sLinkHref){
    if (sLinkHref.match(/youtube\.com\/watch/i)) {
  this.flash = true;
        var hRef = sLinkHref;
        var videoId = hRef.split('=');
        this.videoID = videoId[1];
        this.so = new SWFObject("http://www.youtube.com/v/"+this.videoID, "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0");
        this.so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/metacafe\.com\/watch/i)) {
  this.flash = true;
        var hRef = sLinkHref;
        var videoId = hRef.split('/');
        this.videoID = videoId[4];
        this.so = new SWFObject("http://www.metacafe.com/fplayer/"+this.videoID+"/.swf", "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0");
        this.so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/google\.com\/videoplay/i)) {
  this.flash = true;
        var hRef = sLinkHref;
        var videoId = hRef.split('=');
        this.videoID = videoId[1];
        this.so = new SWFObject("http://video.google.com/googleplayer.swf?docId="+this.videoID+"&hl=en", "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0");
        this.so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/ifilm\.com\/video/i)) {
      this.flash = true;
        var hRef = sLinkHref;
        var videoId = hRef.split('video/');
        this.videoID = videoId[1];
        this.so = new SWFObject("http://www.ifilm.com/efp", "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0", "#000");
        this.so.addVariable("flvbaseclip", this.videoID+"&");
        this.so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/\.mov/i)) {
      this.flash = false;
        if (navigator.plugins && navigator.plugins.length) {
      this.other ='<object id="qtboxMovie" type="video/quicktime" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" data="'+sLinkHref+'" width="'+this.options.contentsWidth+'" height="'+this.options.contentsHeight+'"><param name="src" value="'+sLinkHref+'" /><param name="scale" value="aspect" /><param name="controller" value="true" /><param name="autoplay" value="true" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" /><param name="enablejavascript" value="true" /></object>';
  } else {
    this.other = '<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" width="'+this.options.contentsWidth+'" height="'+this.options.contentsHeight+'" id="qtboxMovie"><param name="src" value="'+sLinkHref+'" /><param name="scale" value="aspect" /><param name="controller" value="true" /><param name="autoplay" value="true" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" /><param name="enablejavascript" value="true" /></object>';
  }
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/\.wmv/i) || sLinkHref.match(/\.asx/i)) {
    this.flash = false;
     this.other = '<object NAME="Player" WIDTH="'+this.options.contentsWidth+'" HEIGHT="'+this.options.contentsHeight+'" align="left" hspace="0" type="application/x-oleobject" CLASSID="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"><param NAME="URL" VALUE="'+sLinkHref+'"><param><param NAME="AUTOSTART" VALUE="false"></param><param name="showControls" value="true"></param><embed WIDTH="'+this.options.contentsWidth+'" HEIGHT="'+this.options.contentsHeight+'" align="left" hspace="0" SRC="'+sLinkHref+'" TYPE="application/x-oleobject" AUTOSTART="false"></embed></object>'
    }
    else if (sLinkHref.match(/\.flv/i)) {
     this.flash = true;
     this.so = new SWFObject(this.options.flvplayer+"?file="+sLinkHref, "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0", "#000");
    }
    else {
      this.flash = true;
        this.videoID = sLinkHref;
        this.so = new SWFObject(this.videoID, "flvvideo", this.options.contentsWidth, this.options.contentsHeight, "0");
    }
},

nextEffect: function(){
    switch (this.step++){
    case 1:
        this.fx.center.start({'width': [this.options.contentsWidth], 'marginLeft': [this.options.contentsWidth/-2]});
        break;
        this.step++;
    case 2:
        this.center.setStyle('background','#fff');
        this.flash ? this.so.write(this.center) : this.center.setHTML(this.other) ;
        this.bottomContainer.setStyles({top: (this.top + this.center.clientHeight)+'px', height: '0px', marginLeft: this.center.style.marginLeft, width: this.options.contentsWidth+'px',display: ''});
        if (this.options.animateCaption){
            this.fx.bottom.set(-this.bottom.offsetHeight);
            this.bottomContainer.style.height = '';
            this.fx.bottom.start(0);
            break;
        }
        this.bottomContainer.style.height = '';
        this.step++;
    }
},

close: function(){
    this.fx.overlay.start(0);
    this.center.style.display = this.bottomContainer.style.display = 'none';
    this.center.innerHTML = '';
    return false;
}};window.addEvent('domready', Videobox.init.bind(Videobox));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use [YouTube's IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) if you want the video to work on an iPhone.  The other API's used to embed the video don't support HTML5 video formats and embed the video using Flash, which is not supported by iOS.  The IFrame API can work with your example because it's still a Javascript API that can be initialized and called when you open the light box.  If the width of the viewport is less than the width of the viewport (i.e. the user is on a mobile device), I wouldn't even bother opening the light box.

Alternatively, you should be able to link to your video in this format to force it to use the HTML5 player: `youtube.com/embed/2sAnENc6ObI?html5=1`

**EDIT**:

Using the above URL, you can embed this using the VideoBox plugin if you modify the the plugin with the below `else if` block added to the `video` function:

```
else if (sLinkHref.match(/youtube\.com\/embed/i)) {
    this.flash = false;
    this.other = "<iframe type='text/html' width='640' height='385' src='" + sLinkHref + "' frameborder='0'></iframe>"; 
}
```

Comment: Can this be done within the URL, or will I need to implement their Javascript?

Comment: You can try adding this URL parameter to the end up any YouTube video URL: html5=1.  I tried this with the video in your example and it doesn't work probably because there isn't an HTML5 version of that video available so then it falls back to the Flash Player.  Notice, however, that this video changes between the Flash and HTML5 version based on that parameter: http://www.youtube.com/embed/dP15zlyra3c?html5=1

Comment: The lack of HTML5 video won't affect the playback on iOS if I use the Javascript, though. Right?

Comment: So, what are my options to use this particular video on iOS with the Videobox?

Comment: I was wrong.  I copied out the ID of your video and used a different YouTube video format and this seems to work: http://www.youtube.com/embed/2sAnENc6ObI?html5=1

Comment: I just tried this, but it didn't load in my Videobox. My Safari error console didn't show any errors. The video player didn't even load.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26591/discussion-between-jacob-vanscoy-and-kurzweilguy)